# jQuery: Ignore classes inside a <li> element

Tags: jquery

I have following html list:

```
<ul>
<li class="list-group-item ReplyPill">This is my first value<span class="badge badge-pill"><div id="close">X</div></span></li>
<li class="list-group-item ReplyPill">This is my second value<span class="badge badge-pill"><div id="close">X</div></span></li>
(...)
</ul>
```

and I am using this jQuery to get all 'li' elements:

```
let replyOptions = [];
        $('.ReplyPill').each(function () {
            replyOptions.push($(this).text());
        });
```

The problem is that the "X" from the 'div' is also read and my output looks like this: "This is my first valueX"

I already tried ".not('#close')" to exclude the div, but it did not change anything.

So is there a way to ignore the 'div' with the id "close" in the loop?

Comment: use class instead of id, say not class , .not('.close')

Comment: Does not work either

Comment: use .html() and store it into a variable html. then use html.substring(0,html.indexof('<') -1). Perhaps not the best answer but should work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs need to be unique - you need a class instead

Also DIV is not a valid child of a span

Anyway

```js
let replyOptions = $('.ReplyPill').map(function() {
  return $(this).contents().get(0).nodeValue; 
}).get();

console.log(replyOptions);


// PS how to delegate the click on the X

$("#list").on("click",".close",function() {
  $(this).closest("li").hide(); 
})
```

```css
li {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li class="list-group-item ReplyPill">This is my first value<span class="badge badge-pill close">X</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item ReplyPill">This is my second value<span class="badge badge-pill close">X</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Exclusions in selectors are a little tricky, especially when dealing with text nodes. A simpler approach would be to wrap the text you want to retrieve in its own element and target it directly.

Also note that it's invalid HTML to place `div` elements inside `span`. In addition, you can use `map()` to build your array more effectively. Try this:

```js
let replyOptions = $('.ReplyPill span.value').map((i, el) => el.textContent).get();
console.log(replyOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list-group-item ReplyPill">
    <span class="value">This is my first value</span>
    <span class="badge badge-pill close">X</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item ReplyPill">
    <span class="value">This is my second value</span>
    <span class="badge badge-pill">X</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```